# Realizar telnet utlizando proxy com python

Tags: python, socket, telnet

Estou tentando realizar um `telnet` na porta **SSH 22**, utlizando o `pysocks`, porem parece que o **SOCKS** nao esta conectando, porem se eu utlizar o programa [Open Text Socks Client Dasboard](https://www.opentext.com.br/o-que-fazemos/produtos/specialty-technologies/connectivity/socks-client) ele conecta, mas preciso fazer isso pelo python, esse programa e para Windows e o SCRIPT será executado em uma maquina LINUX

**SCRIPT**

```
import socket
import socks
import requests
import os
import pymssql


socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "meu-ip", 1080, True, 'usuario','senha')
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

socks(os.system('telnet meu-ip 22'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Connecting To MEU-IP...Could not open connection to the host, on
>   port 22: Connect failed Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "teste2.py", line 11, in 
>       socks(os.system('telnet meu-ip 22')) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Isso ai está bem confuso, Telnet é na porta 21, então a menos que o servidor esteja rodando o telnet na porta 22 isso nunca vai dar certo.
Outra coisa, se você vai executar o comando telnet direto no SO que é o que acontece na ultima linha, você não precisa de sockets, basta que o SO tenha um cliente telnet nativo.

Comment: @CarlosHMarques o cliente so pode ser acesso por proxy

Comment: preciso fazer mais q um telnet, mas achei q seria um bom exemplo o telnet

Comment: eu estou testando a porta 22 para conexao SSH